# Set 3 seekbars to change RGB channels

Tags: android, rgb, android-seekbar

I'm following this guy that wrote a code that change background color based on RGB channels assigned to 3 different seekbars, so R to one sk, G to another and B to another one.

The problem is that I can't get the code to work:

```
private int seekR, seekG, seekB;    

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_color_changer);

    SeekBar sbR = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.RedSeekBar);
    SeekBar sbG = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.GreenSeekBar);
    SeekBar sbB = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.BlueSeekBar);

    mySeekBarChangeListener msbclR = new mySeekBarChangeListener();
    mySeekBarChangeListener msbclG = new mySeekBarChangeListener();
    mySeekBarChangeListener msbclB = new mySeekBarChangeListener();

    sbR.setonseekBarChangeListener(msbclR);
    sbG.setonseekBarChangeListener(msbclG);
    sbB.setonseekBarChangeListener(msbclB);

    msbclR.onprogressChanged(sbR, sbR.getProgress(), false);
    msbclG.onprogressChanged(sbG, sbG.getProgress(), false);
    msbclB.onprogressChanged(sbB, sbB.getProgress(), false);

}
```

This text give me an error almost everywhere, whatever, nothing seems to work. I just want to know why.. Do I have to set something based on that mySeekBarChangeListener? Thanks in advance!

Comment: -1, You're essentially asking for code review, and didn't even post the specific errors you got.

Comment: @AmandaS not my intention. Maybe it seems to because I was confused about the code, but I didn't want to ask for a specific portion because I was curious about this new (for me) kind of code. However, my question was why this code wouldn't work even if it is correct, I mean there's no error. Sorry for my english, hope I have clarified :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should work:

```
private int seekR, seekG, seekB;    

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_color_changer);

    SeekBar sbR = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.RedSeekBar);
    SeekBar sbG = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.GreenSeekBar);
    SeekBar sbB = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.BlueSeekBar);

    sbR.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            seekR = progress;

            doSomethingWithColor();
        }
    });

    sbG.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            seekG = progress;

            doSomethingWithColor();
        }
    });

    sbB.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            seekB = progress;

            doSomethingWithColor();
        }
    });

}

private void doSomethingWithColor() {
    int color = Color.rgb(seekR, seekG, seekB);
    // Do something with color
}
```

or more compact

```
private int seekR, seekG, seekB;    

private SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener onSeekBarChangeListener = new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        switch (seekBar.getId()) {
        case R.id.RedSeekBar:
            seekR = progress;
            break;
        case R.id.GreenSeekBar:
            seekG = progress;
            break;
        case R.id.BlueSeekBar:
            seekB = progress;
            break;
        }

        doSomethingWithColor();
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_color_changer);

    SeekBar sbR = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.RedSeekBar);
    SeekBar sbG = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.GreenSeekBar);
    SeekBar sbB = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.BlueSeekBar);

    sbR.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(onSeekBarChangeListener);
    sbG.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(onSeekBarChangeListener);
    sbB.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(onSeekBarChangeListener);

}

private void doSomethingWithColor() {
    int color = Color.rgb(seekR, seekG, seekB);
    // Do something with color
}
```

another one

```
private int seekR, seekG, seekB;    

public class MySeekBarChangeListener implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        switch (seekBar.getId()) {
        case R.id.RedSeekBar:
            seekR = progress;
            break;
        case R.id.GreenSeekBar:
            seekG = progress;
            break;
        case R.id.BlueSeekBar:
            seekB = progress;
            break;
        }

        doSomethingWithColor();
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_color_changer);

    SeekBar sbR = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.RedSeekBar);
    SeekBar sbG = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.GreenSeekBar);
    SeekBar sbB = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.BlueSeekBar);

    MySeekBarChangeListener msbclR = new MySeekBarChangeListener();
    MySeekBarChangeListener msbclG = new MySeekBarChangeListener();
    MySeekBarChangeListener msbclB = new MySeekBarChangeListener();

    sbR.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(msbclR);
    sbG.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(msbclG);
    sbB.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(msbclB);

}

private void doSomethingWithColor() {
    int color = Color.rgb(seekR, seekG, seekB);
    // Do something with color
}
```